# Xpath одинаковые элементы, но нужен конкретный

Tags: java, html, css, xpath

У меня есть меню отображения input элементов.
Рядом есть иконки на подобие обычных чекпоинтов отвечающие за отображение того или иного input на сайте. Таких у меня примерно 15 штук. Как мне выхватывать конкретный чекпоинт конкретного input, для написания теста?

Код как пример, у меня другой но чтобы понять как примерно выглядит ситуация.

```
<div>
<p><input><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="скрыть/отобразить">скрыть/отобразить</p>
<p><input><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="скрыть/отобразить">скрыть/отобразить</p>
<p><input><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="скрыть/отобразить">скрыть/отобразить</p>
<p><input><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="скрыть/отобразить">скрыть/отобразить</p>
<p><input><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="скрыть/отобразить">скрыть/отобразить</p>
<p><input><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="скрыть/отобразить">скрыть/отобразить</p>
<p><input><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="скрыть/отобразить">скрыть/отобразить</p>
<p><input><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="скрыть/отобразить">скрыть/отобразить</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте им какой-то идентификатор, может `data-id`, или типа того. Можно по конкретному индексу искать, но затея такая себе.

Comment: У них наверное должны быть разные name, иначе это вообще бессмысленно. Так что можно по атрибуту выбирать